# freebsd-update patches custom /boot/kernel/kernel which breaks remote access

Tags: updates, freebsd, software-update

I am running `freebsd-update` from time to time on my FreeBSD 9.0 system. I have a custom kernel installed and running and, according to a tip from the FreeBSD documentation ([Freebsd Update](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html) (section 25.2.2)), keep a copy of `GENERIC` in `/boot/GENERIC`

> Note: It is a good idea to always keep a copy of the `GENERIC` kernel in `/boot/GENERIC`. It will be helpful in diagnosing a variety of problems, and in performing version upgrades using freebsd-update as described in Section 25.2.3.

When there are updates I keep getting the following message from `freebsd-update`:

> The following files will be updated as part of updating to `9.0-RELEASE-p4`: `/boot/kernel/kernel`

And `freebsd-update` sure enough seems to overwrite my (custom) kernel with `GENERIC` in the process of updating. This breaks remote access to the machine for me because things in my custom kernel are needed for networking...

I believe that the problem is that FreeBSD or `freebsd-update` does not recognise my custom kernel as custom but thinks it's `GENERIC`. Question is: why? And how can I change this?

I found the following post [explaining how to install the GENERIC kernel into /boot](http://forums.freebsd.org/showpost.php?p=65265&postcount=17) and I am wondering if this would help. Does the procedure explained there

```
#cd $PlaceWhereTheISOIsMounted/8.0-RELEASE/kernels/
# ./install.sh GENERIC
```

"register" somehow that `GENERIC` is in `/boot/GENERIC` instead of `/boot/kernel/`?

---

By the way: yes, [Machine boots GENERIC kernel after freebsd-update install](https://serverfault.com/q/425697/48229) on serverfault is the same issue (not solved there, got carried away).

---

**UPDATE**
Other people are experiencing the same issue: [How to keep freebsd-update from trashing custom kernel?](http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/How-to-keep-freebsd-update-from-trashing-custom-kernel-td5733932.html)

---

**UPDATE2**
According to the FreeBSD mailing list the hint in the documentation about keeping a copy of GENERIC around does not help/work (anymore). See [freebsd-update patches custom /boot/kernel/kernel which it should not](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2013-January/247763.html)

Answer (score 1):

A quote from the handbook:

> Only the GENERIC kernel can be automatically updated by freebsd-update.

If you need a network driver that is not built in the GENERIC kernel, see if it is available as a module and load it automatically from `/boot/loader.conf`. Then you can stick with GENERIC.

If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to do a build from source.